# Mysql zero rows, but large size table

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following Query, and the topmost row (the largest one) read: rows:0, Size:22Mb. The table has no rows when I click on it (PhpMyAdmin), but where are gone the 22Mb? Am I missing anything? Thanks

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table", 
table_rows AS "Rows", ROUND( (
data_length + index_length
) /1024/1024, 2 ) AS Size_Mb
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema = 'myDB'
ORDER BY Size_Mb desc LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: what do you see when you physically select this table?

Comment: Are these `InnoDB` or `MyISAM` tables?

Comment: Read the descriptions of `index_length` and `data_length` at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html. These are the sizes of files or index memory, which may have unused space if you've deleted rows.

Comment: I Just fired a Truncate Table, and got rid of it. But still curious on how it could be 22Mb..

Comment: take a look at `data_length` and `index_length` separately in your query.

Comment: How many rows do you have on that particular table before truncated?

Comment: Zero rows. I just truncated the Table. Thanks everyone, case closed.

Comment: *"still curious on how it could be 22Mb."*  Tables do not shrink when rows are deleted.